# How to use swift convert string to ipv6 addr

Tags: swift, ipv6

I have a ipv6 string,how to use Swift convert to  in6_addr

```
let ipString = "2001:0b28:f23f:f005:0000:0000:0000:000a"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inet_pton()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_ntop.html)
similarly as you would in a C program:

```
let ipString = "2001:0b28:f23f:f005:0000:0000:0000:000a"
var addr = in6_addr()
let retval = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&addr) {
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipString, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))    
}

if retval == 0 {
    print("Invalid address")
} else if retval == -1 {
    print("Failed:", String.fromCString(strerror(errno)) ?? "\(errno)")
    // For Swift 3, replace the last line by
    // print("Failed:", String(cString: strerror(errno)))
} else {
  //  Success, `addr` contains the result.
}
```

`withUnsafeMutablePointer()` is necessary to pass the address of
the `addr` variable to `inet_pton()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 & Network**

You can use `IPv6Address` from `Network` to work with IPv6 addresses. It is useful for working with local or remote endpoints `NWEndpoints`, for validating string IPv6 addresses, shortening etc.

There is a extension of `IPv6Address` that implements helper functions for `in6_addr`:

```swift
import Network

extension IPv6Address {
    var address: in6_addr {
        rawValue.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.load(as: in6_addr.self)
        }
    }
    
    var stringValue: String { debugDescription }
    
    init(_ address: in6_addr) {
        var addr = address
        let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: &addr) { Data($0) }
        self.init(data)!
    }
}
```

How to use:

```swift
let ipString = "2001:0b28:f23f:f005:0000:0000:0000:000a"

// Create IPv6Address from string
if let ipv6 = IPv6Address(ipString) {
    // Get in6_addr from IPv6Address
    let addr = ipv6.address
    print(addr) // in6_addr(__u6_addr: __C.in6_addr.__Unnamed_union___u6_addr())
    
    // Create IPv6Address from in6_addr
    let ipv6 = IPv6Address(addr)
    print(ipv6.stringValue) // 2001:b28:f23f:f005::a
}
```